# Timed arithmetic quiz

Tags: java, timer, quiz

In this program you have to solve 20 exercises. The time you need will be measured. If you break a record, you'll get an entry in the highscore list.

[The program can be downloaded here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sowvhn0010jinn9/Mathematician.jar?dl=0)
You can only start it via command line, not by double-click.

If I can improve my code to make it more readable, please tell me how.

**Main.java**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().mainLoop();
    }

    private static String saveName = ".mathematicianSave";
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private RecordList recordList;

    public Main() {
        if (new File(saveName).exists()) {
            try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(saveName))) {
                recordList = (RecordList)ois.readObject();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            recordList = new RecordList(5);
        }
    }

    private void mainLoop() {
        System.out.println("[0] Leave\n");
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("[1] Play");
            System.out.println("[2] Highscore");
            System.out.print("Input: ");
            String decision = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println();
            if (decision.equals("1")) {
                calculate();
            } else if (decision.equals("2")) {
                showHighscore();
            } else if (decision.equals("0")) {
                save();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void calculate() {
        System.out.println("Division exercises have to be solved without rest.");
        System.out.println("You have to solve twenty exercises.");
        System.out.println("Be as fast as you can!\n");

        Instant startTime = Instant.now();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            Exercise exercise = Exercise.getRandomExercise();
            System.out.print(exercise);
            int guess = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
            exercise.solve(guess);
            if (!exercise.solve(guess)) {
                System.out.println("\nYou have made a mistake.");
                System.out.println("More luck next time.\n");
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();

        Instant endTime = Instant.now();
        Duration timeElapsed = Duration.between(startTime, endTime);
        double seconds = timeElapsed.toMillis() / 1000.0;

        Record record = new Record(seconds);
        System.out.println("You have needed " + seconds + " seconds.");
        if (recordList.add(record)) {
            System.out.println("You have set a new record!");
            System.out.print("Your name: ");
            record.setName(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private void showHighscore() {
        System.out.println(recordList);
    }

    private void save() {
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(saveName))) {
            oos.writeObject(recordList);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Exercise.java**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Exercise {
    private int number1;
    private int number2;
    private int solution;
    private String operationSymbol;

    private Exercise(int number1, int number2, int solution, String operationSymbol) {
        this.number1 = number1;
        this.number2 = number2;
        this.solution = solution;
        this.operationSymbol = operationSymbol;
    }

    public static Exercise getRandomExercise() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int choice = random.nextInt(4);

        int number1;
        int number2;
        int solution;
        String operationSymbol;
        if (choice == 0) {
            number1 = random.nextInt(26);
            number2 = random.nextInt(26);
            solution = number1 + number2;
            operationSymbol = "+";
        } else if (choice == 1) {
            number1 = random.nextInt(16) + 10;
            number2 = random.nextInt(26);
            solution = number1 - number2;
            operationSymbol = "-";          
        } else if (choice == 2) {
            number1 = random.nextInt(15) + 1;
            number2 = random.nextInt(15) + 1;
            solution = number1 * number2;
            operationSymbol = "*";          
        } else {
            number1 = random.nextInt(151);
            number2 = random.nextInt(15) + 1;
            solution = number1 / number2;
            operationSymbol = "/";          
        }
        return new Exercise(number1, number2, solution, operationSymbol);
    }

    public boolean solve(int guess) {
        return solution == guess;
    }

    @Override 
    public String toString() {
        return number1 + " " + operationSymbol + " " + number2 + " = ";
    }
}
```

**Record.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Record implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private double seconds;

    public Record(double seconds) {
        name = null;
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }

    public Record(String name, double seconds) {
        this.name = name;
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getSeconds() {
        return seconds;
    }
}
```

**RecordList.java**

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class RecordList implements Serializable {
    private List<Record> records;
    private int limit;

    public RecordList(int limit) {
        records = new ArrayList<>();
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    private void sort() {
        records.sort(new Comparator<Record>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Record record1, Record record2) {
                Double double1 = record1.getSeconds();
                Double double2 = record2.getSeconds();
                return double1.compareTo(double2);
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean add(Record record) {
        if (records.size() < limit) {
            records.add(record);
            sort();
            return true;
        }

        Record lowestRecord = records.get(records.size() - 1);
        if (record.getSeconds() < lowestRecord.getSeconds()) {
            records.remove(lowestRecord);
            records.add(record);
            sort();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (records.isEmpty()) {
            return "No records.\n";
        }
        StringBuilder returnValue = new StringBuilder("--- Records ---\n\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
            returnValue.append(i+1);
            returnValue.append(". ");
            returnValue.append(records.get(i).getName());
            returnValue.append(" - ");
            returnValue.append(records.get(i).getSeconds());
            returnValue.append("\n");
        }
        return returnValue.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find your code very readable.

- "Division exercises have to be solved without rest"  should instead read "division exercises should be solved without remainders" or something.  "without rest" doesn't mean anything to me.
- It is crashing when symbols like / and . are used in an answer, instead remind user of above rule.  In general, handle invalid input instead of having program crash.
- Consider a validation using a modulus test for the division exercises to make sure the random numbers generated and divided have a whole number for the answer.  If not, get another random number.
- Goal is to persist high score so that it is available next time the program is launched.  Main.java looks like it should persist this high score to a file called .mathematicianSave but it does not unless I chose to exit at the menu with 0.  Most of my exits have been because of crashes.
- Menu item [0] Leave only appears when program first launches
- in the getRandomExercise() method, I would not hard code the upper limits for number1 and number2 but instead use a variable declared at start of method.
- in the calculate() method of Main class, I would also not hard code the 5 but instead make it a variable called numberOfQuestions and declare it at start of method.